# How to fix error in toggling div?

Tags: jquery, webkit

I am showing/hiding a div depending where I click with this code:

```
$("body").click(function(e) {
    if(e.target.id == ".userNavBar") {
        $(".dropdownInfo").css({ 'display' : 'block'});
        $('.userNavBar').css({'background-color' : '#444'});
        $('.upperBar').css({'border-top-color' : '#ff556f'});
    } else {
        $(".dropdownInfo").css({ 'display' : 'none'});
        $('.userNavBar').css({'background-color' : '#333'});
        $('.upperBar').css({'border-top-color' : '#333'});
    }
});
```

When I click on `.userNavBar`, nothing happens, and when I inspect element for errors and warnings, 4 of these errors pop up for each click:
*"event.layerX and event.layerY are broken and deprecated in WebKit. They will be removed from the engine in the near future."*

How do I fix this?? And what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are confusing ids and classes.

But if I'm reading what you are trying to do correctly, you might be better off with something like this:

```
$(function() {
  function toggleMenu(show) {
    $(".dropdownInfo").toggle(show);
    $('.userNavBar').css('background-color', show ? '#444' : '#333');
    $('.upperBar').css('border-top-color', show ? '#ff556f' : '#333');
  };
  $('.userNavBar').click(function(e) {
    toggleMenu(true);
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
  $("body").click(function(e) {
    toggleMenu(false);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this but registering on click events on the whole body off the document is not great practice

```
$("body").click(function(e) {
    if($(this).class() == ".userNavBar") {
        $(".dropdownInfo").css({ 'display' : 'block'});
        $('.userNavBar').css({'background-color' : '#444'});
        $('.upperBar').css({'border-top-color' : '#ff556f'});
    } else {
        $(".dropdownInfo").css({ 'display' : 'none'});
        $('.userNavBar').css({'background-color' : '#333'});
        $('.upperBar').css({'border-top-color' : '#333'});
    }
});
```